# connecting D3 visualization with Apache storm

Tags: javascript, d3.js, apache-storm

**Problem**

Can somebody help me figure out why the visualization is not working.I cannot figure how to connect data coming from twitter via Apache storm to d3.

**What I am Doing?**
I'm working on Real Time Anayltics.

Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <body>
         <script type="text/javascript">
var w = 300,                        //width
h = 300,                            //height
r = 100,                            //radius



  var source = new EventSource('/stream');
  var team={};
  var sentiment={};

   source.onmessage = function (event) {
     team=event.data.split("|")[0];
     sentiment=event.data.split("|")[1];

   };
color = d3.scale.category20c();     //builtin range of colors
data = [{"label":team, "value":sentiment}
        // ,{"label":"two", "value":50},
        // {"label":"three", "value":30}
      ];

var vis = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg:svg")              //create the SVG element inside the <body>
    .data([data])                   //associate our data with the document
        .attr("width", w)           //set the width and height of our visualization (these will be attributes of the <svg> tag
        .attr("height", h)
    .append("svg:g")                //make a group to hold our pie chart
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")")    //move the center of the pie chart from 0, 0 to radius, radius
var arc = d3.svg.arc()              //this will create <path> elements for us using arc data
    .outerRadius(r);
var pie = d3.layout.pie()           //this will create arc data for us given a list of values
    .value(function(d) { return d.value; });    //we must tell it out to access the value of each element in our data array
var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")     //this selects all <g> elements with class slice (there aren't any yet)
    .data(pie)                          //associate the generated pie data (an array of arcs, each having startAngle, endAngle and value properties)
    .enter()                            //this will create <g> elements for every "extra" data element that should be associated with a selection. The result is creating a <g> for every object in the data array
        .append("svg:g")                //create a group to hold each slice (we will have a <path> and a <text> element associated with each slice)
            .attr("class", "slice");    //allow us to style things in the slices (like text)
    arcs.append("svg:path")
            .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); } ) //set the color for each slice to be chosen from the color function defined above
            .attr("d", arc);                                    //this creates the actual SVG path using the associated data (pie) with the arc drawing function
    arcs.append("svg:text")                                     //add a label to each slice
            .attr("transform", function(d) {                    //set the label's origin to the center of the arc
            //we have to make sure to set these before calling arc.centroid
            d.innerRadius = 0;
            d.outerRadius = r;
            return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";        //this gives us a pair of coordinates like [50, 50]
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")                          //center the text on it's origin
        .text(function(d, i) { return data[i].label; });        //get the label from our original data array

             </script>
           </body>
         </html>
```

`

Comment: You're talking about two rather different technologies, most likely people interested in one won't know about the other. Try to split at the middle point for simplicity: do you actually get data? If yes, what does it look like?

Comment: Also, you have variables `team` and `sentiment` which are defined in an `onmessage` callback, but used in the main code: so they are used before being defined: this cannot be right.